# XML XSL Transform From Stream

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

Hi I have a memory stream in which I use XMLTextWriter to write out some XML.  What I want to do is transform this XML using the XSL.transform feature.  The thing is I don't want to create a temp. XML file, I want to somehow use the stream to Transform it into the XSL.  Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Just use an XmlReader and pass it to the Transform method. You'll need to seek to the start of the stream first.

```
  stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);
  XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
  transform.Load(...load your transform...);
  transform.Transform(reader, resultsWriter);
```

I've obviously removed certain elements here to simplify the code, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Worth noting that your transform can be loaded from many things including a stream by the above Load method.  You should never need to drop down to a file.