# Processing Large XML file in .NET

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, bigdata

I want to deserialize XML file, make some transformation on it's content, and serialize it back to another file. The problem is, that my XML file i want to deserialize has 200 gigabytes of data. Obviously I can't deserialize it all into memory. What I have to do, is deserialize, transform, and serialize data in chunks. XML schema is pretty straight-forward:

```
<root>
    <node>
        <title>SomeNodeTitle1</title>
        <text>Some Node Text 1. A lot of Text.</text>
    </node>
    <node>
        <title>SomeNodeTitle2</title>
        <text>Some Node Text 2. A lot of Text.</text>
    </node>
    <node>
        <title>SomeNodeTitle3</title>
        <text>Some Node Text 3. A lot of Text.</text>
    </node>
    <node>
        <title>SomeNodeTitle4</title>
        <text>Some Node Text 4. A lot of Text.</text>
    </node>
</root>
```

I want (more or less) something like this:

```
OpenInputFile();
OpenOutputFile(); // Write root node tag

while(there_are_any_unprocessed_nodes_in_file)
{
    List<Node> nodes = TakeNodeChunk();
    Transform(nodes); // Let's say remove all "cat" word occurences in text
    AppendNodesToOutputXmlFile(nodes);
}

CloseInputFile();
CloseOutputFile(); // Close root node tag
```

Obviously I cannot use this construction:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);

Root root = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```

becouse it'll throw an exception when reading such big file.

What can I do about it, what can I use to make chunk *read*, *transform*, *write* possible?

Comment: First Enumerate all records and create a static buffer in example for 1000 records or as you need..Then iterate needed records into buffer, transform to your callee and release buffer content or replace/update the buffer contents with new ones

Comment: Would using streams be an option? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541900/xml-xsl-transform-from-stream

Comment: @Marvin Smit Yes. Everything that serves desired purpose is an option.

Comment: Are you sure you want/need to _deserialize_ ? The description doesn't call for that.

Comment: A very efficient way would be applying an XSL. Otherwise: use an XmlReader and an XmlWriter and do your logic in between.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform some work manually.
You can read from file in chunks (try make chunk ≈x2 size of typical node, if possible).

```
while (hasSomethingToDo)
{   
  while (!StringBuffer.Contains("</node>"))
  {
    StringBuffer += ReadStringFromOutput (bufferSize: 2*TYPICAL_NODE_SIZE)
  }
  while (StringBuffer.Contains("</node>")) //if node is large, you should optimize here
  {
    CutStringBuffer(out cuttedPart, out leftover, "<node>", "</node>");
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Node));
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(cuttedPart))
    {
      Node node = (Node)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
      node = TransformNode(node);
     WriteToOuput(node);
    }
    StringBuffer = leftover;
  }
}
```

Comment: Also you should remove whitespaces before tags, and output errors or warnings when XML schema doesn't match your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Another option will be use of http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xmlnodereader.aspx